# Hide/Show content based on cookie

Tags: cookies

I have code to add a cookie to a page, it is very simple:

```
function setup_user() {
    if (is_page(21)) {
        setcookie("user_type", "advanced", time()+157680000);
    }
}
add_action( 'get_header', 'setup_user');
```

if the user goes to a certain page, they are an advanced user and do not need to see basic help items.  So now I want to hide some content on some pages.

I currently use the Quotes plugin to manage the content that should be shown/hidden.  I know I can add conditional logic:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE["user_type"])) {
    // then the content should not show.
}
```

How can I check that cookie, and based on it show/hide content on any page of the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea is to use some CSS if you want to apply this logic to many elements on different pages.

You can add this code to `header.php` for example :

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE["user_type"])) {
    <style>.hide_content {display:none!important}</style>
}
```

Then you can simply add the CSS class to all elements you want to hide when cookies are set.

Comment: That is a fantastic idea!! Going to try it.

Comment: @nycynik and let me know if it's working fine ;)

Comment: This works great!  Very easy to implement, and works on everything, this was a brilliant suggestion, saved me a ton of time!